# How to Average a column of results in sql query

Tags: sql

I have a query which pulls the number of active customers and finds the total number of days the customer has been active... I would like to find the average of this column...

Is it possible to pull the average and display it on 1 line in a query like this?  Or would this need to be done on the reporting side?  My current query is:

```
SELECT        
   dtCreated, bActive, dtLastUpdated, dtLastVisit, 
   DATEDIFF(d, dtCreated, dtLastUpdated) AS Difference
FROM 
   Customers
WHERE        
   (bActive = 'true') 
   AND (dtLastUpdated > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
```

Thanks.

Comment: All rows in the result set of a query have the same number of rows.  You have three choices:  (1) do this in the application; (2) add the average column to all rows; (3) calculate the average in a separate query.

Comment: I tried to just add average (difference) prior to the post, but it said "average is not recognized built in function"

Comment: @Shmewnix you should edit your question to include an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AVG: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677

```
SELECT         
   dtCreated, bActive, dtLastUpdated, dtLastVisit,  
   DATEDIFF(d, dtCreated, dtLastUpdated) AS Difference,
   AVG(DATEDIFF(d, dtCreated, dtLastUpdated)) OVER() AS AvgDifference
FROM  
   Customers 
WHERE         
   (bActive = 'true')  
   AND (dtLastUpdated > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
```

Updated it to use OVER(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: Invalid column name if I use "AVG".  The problem is I want the "Difference" Column, and the average column, but the average should only be 1 output.

Comment: So you want an extra column that returns the Average difference across all rows? Do what Erica suggested in conjunction with the OVER clause: AVG(DATEDIFF(d, dtCreated, dtLastUpdated)) OVER ()

Comment: @JustinSwartsel that makes a lot more sense - I updated the comment to reflect this improvement.

Comment: It looks like it works... any idea why there would be an error while parsing? error is: The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported.